# Problems with Drawing Marker & Saving It Using Signed-In Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the Maps API, on map `click` event I draw a marker on Google Maps. I then attach a `click` event on the marker itself to open an infoWindow, which would allow the user to save that location as a "favorite" in Google Maps. This is based on the documentation I found regarding [Signed-In Maps.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin?hl=en)

[In my example](http://jsfiddle.net/zjk5s5o7/), you can see that if you draw a marker close to a place that already exists on Google Maps (try Google's HQ), then the 'Save to Google Maps' hyperlink works properly in the infoWindow. If you draw the marker on map and it is not close to a place (try the water body), the 'Save to Google Maps' link does not work, as it remains inactive. Note: if you want to try this, you have to be signed into a Google account.

Why is this? I can't find a proper answer. The [support documentation](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3184808?hl=en) states that:

> Click or search for a place on the map. This can be a business, place,
>   or a **set of latitude and longitude coordinates**.

On the map `click` event, I am essentially passing a pair of lat & lng coordinates. So shouldn't it work *anywhere* on the map, regardless of where I click?

Here is the code for the map click event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        place: {
            location: {
                lat: event.latLng.lat(), // Capture lat on click event
                lng: event.latLng.lng()  // Capture lng on click event
            },
            query: 'Google, Sydney, Australia'

        },
        attribution: {
            source: 'Google Maps JavaScript API',
            webUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/'
        }
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'This is a test.'
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function () {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. The relevant documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin?hl=en#save_to_google_maps_with_an_info_window). Note it says:

> A query string to search for places *near* to the location

(emphasis mine)

In other words, it is a requirement that the query string resolves to a point that is close to the location parameter. The intention is to ensure that the user is not misled into saving a place that is in fact nowhere near where the marker has been placed on the map.